# Как правильно расположить элементы,чтобы они не выходили за границей экрана?

Tags: android, xml

Здравствуйте.До запуска приложение оно выглядит следующим образом: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде высота button-ов равны. Но после запуска приложение,оно выглядит таким образом: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите последний элемент выходит с границы экрана или её высота уменьшилась. А также высота Button-ов уже не равны.Почему так происходит? Что нужно сделать чтобы так не происходило ? Вот xml код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:text="Вопрос"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="185dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/QuestionText"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    >

    <Button
        android:text="Предыдущий"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:textColor="#000"
        android:background="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:text="Следующий"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:textColor="#000"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:onClick="ShowNextQuestion"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

    <Button
        android:text="Ответ А"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:onClick="OptionButtonPressed"
        android:id="@+id/opta"
        android:background="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:text="Ответ В"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/optb"
        android:onClick="OptionButtonPressed"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:text="Ответ С"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:onClick="OptionButtonPressed"
        android:id="@+id/optc" />

    <Button
        android:text="Ответ D"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:onClick="OptionButtonPressed"
        android:id="@+id/optd" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Для чего кнопки по две в отдельный контейнерах?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте относительную разметку RelativeLayout. Таким образом, можно задать динамические размеры всем элементам и разместить их - некоторые внизу экрана, другие над ними. Некоторые вверху экрана, некоторые под ними.

В вашем текущем случае, общего пространства не хватает для того, чтобы вместить всё заданные элементы, так как они имеют чёткие размеры, например

```
70dp
```